How can I retrieve the prerender-manifest.js file and other .json and .js files?
I've been working on editing a website source code my friend sent me. Initially, everything ran smoothly, but after making some changes and running npm run build, certain .json and .js files went missing from the .next folder. Now, the code isn't functioning as expected. Any insights on what might be going wrong? Thanks in advance for the help!
Image 1 is the before and Image 2 is the after.


I've attempted running commands like npm run start, npm run dev, and npm run build, but none seem to be working as expected.
Maybe this will help?


I'm not a fan of images of text.  Others agree.

I am extremely sorry!

You could edit your post and replace the image of the error with the original text.  Make use of markdown to format the text verbatim.  You can do so with triple-backtick syntax with a language tag of none.  reference

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
